# spacing between lines inside beamer>frame>textblock*

Tags: beamer, line-spacing, setspace

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable,stackengine}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
%\usepackage{setspace}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{frame title}
\begin{textblock*}{110mm}(10mm,75mm)
{
%\setstretch{0.25}
%\linespread{0.25}
%\fontsize{8}{1}\selectfont
%\baselineskip=200pt
Asad kjl nkgpaoi paosdiop iuwrgnl, poiyirw ighgapwnm, sd dioajlnlg adiglykanfk we gah apjmgns aoijnafk. oiqjeknifal tljlalfajsklfaf akkjflkja adjepofgd jglkle ajiefkenj sopitrnj sfidjiie utiowlp ownknfeo aoioiekrn huehali.
}
\end{textblock*}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Not able to change space between lines. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\setstretch{}` inside the `frame` environment.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable,stackengine}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\usepackage{setspace}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{frame title}
\setstretch{1.5} 
\begin{textblock*}{110mm}(10mm,75mm)
{
Asad kjl nkgpaoi paosdiop iuwrgnl, poiyirw ighgapwnm, sd dioajlnlg adiglykanfk we gah apjmgns aoijnafk. oiqjeknifal tljlalfajsklfaf akkjflkja adjepofgd jglkle ajiefkenj sopitrnj sfidjiie utiowlp ownknfeo aoioiekrn huehali.
}
\end{textblock*}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. This does solve the problem.